# Request coming as C# JObject to Java JSonNode is not coming properly

Tags: java, c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have 2 project, P1(.Net) and P2(Java). A post request sends the object to the P1 and P1 deserializes & sends it to P2. Here is the P1 class of the request object in C#.

```
public class Request
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public JObject Data { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the P2 class of the request object in Java

```
public class Request{
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private JsonNode data;
}
```

When data come to P1, after deserialization the request is full and expected like below.

```
id -> 3
type -> "type1"
data -> {{name: "myRequest", topic: "myTopic"}}
```

However when it hits to the P2 endpoint, the request becomes

```
id -> 3
type -> "type1"
data -> {{name: [], topic: []}}
```

I don't know where is the problem and I need the data variable as JsonNode because its actual type depends on the request type and I need to parse it in P2.
The json in P1 is below

```
{
   "id": "1234",
   "type": "type1",
   "data": 
   {
      "name": "010018",
      "topic": "EGYT"
   }
}
```

The JSON going from P1 to P2 is below

```
{
   "id": "1234",
   "type": "type1",
   "data": 
   {
     "name": [],
     "topic": []
   }
}
```

I found the answer and sharing below

Comment: arent your Java properties of Data array's ?

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik no they are not

Comment: Can you post the actual json that's going on the line from P1 to P2? I would write it out in P1 before sending, in P2 after receiving (the plain json) and maybe intercept the packets with wireshark and check what's actually being sent.

Comment: Everything converts to json string to move from one lang to another. So you have to show a json that was sent to Java.  If it is Ok, then it is a java problem,but we need a json to telll it.

Comment: Now guys, I was busy with fixing the problem, sorry for late reply. I am giving you the json payloads and the answer thank you for your minus point and your concern.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using RestRequest/AddJsonBody method like below

```
Request myRequestPayload; // to show payload type
var client = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest();
var serializedEvent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myRequestPayload);
request.AddJsonBody(serializedEvent);
```

and RestSharp documentation has a warning saying **"Do not send JSON string or some sort of JObject instance to AddJsonBody; it won't work! Use AddStringBody instead."** So I fixed it by changing AddJsonBody with AddStringBody.
https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#url-segment